# creation of a login page in android

Tags: android

```
EditText txtUserName;
 EditText txtPassword;
 Button btnLogin;
 Button btnCancel;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);


     txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
     txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
     btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
         btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {            
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddName.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                 if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
                     Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else{
                     Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                     }
                       }
                          });

 }           
       }
```

i have created a login page for my app. while i am running in my emulator if the password and username matches it should go to next screen but while running this if the username and password is wrong the app is going to second page can anyone suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.app.NewProjectHttpDemo;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

EditText txtUserName;
 EditText txtPassword;
 Button btnLogin;
 Button btnCancel;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);


     txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
     txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
     btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
         btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {            

                 if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddName.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                     Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else{
                     Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                     }
                       }
                          });

 }           
       }
```

Replace this code with your code,this will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
 EditText txtUserName;
 EditText txtPassword;
 Button btnLogin;
 Button btnCancel;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);


     txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
     txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
     btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {            

             if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
                 Intent firstIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                 startActivity(firstIntent);

                } else{
                        Intent secondtIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                 startActivity(secondIntent);
                 }
                   }
                      });
```

}
       }

Answer (score 0):

```
         btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
         btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {                                 
                 if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
                     Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddName.class);
                     startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else{
                     Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                     }
                   }
               });
```